# Error with Notification.Builder in notify

Tags: java, android

Hello I am new to Android, and I 'm trying to create notifications Notification.Builder and I failed . When launching the notification I get error

```
nm.notify(IDNOTIFICACIONUNO,notif); // Error in notif
```

I have downloaded the API 'S 16 17 18 19 23,
 and this is all code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
NotificationManager nm;
private static final int IDNOTIFICACIONUNO = 1;
Notification notif;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button btnLanzar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_notificacion);

btnLanzar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),segundaVentana.class);
 PendingIntent intencionPendiente =  PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,i,0); 

 Notification.Builder notif = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());

notif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tree);
notif.setTicker("App Nature ¡TIP!");
notif.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
notif.setContentTitle("App Nature ¡TIP!");
notif.setContentText("Cierra la llave, cuando te estes cepillando");
notif.setContentInfo("TIP");
notif.setContentIntent(intencionPendiente);

 nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);             
 nm.notify(IDNOTIFICACIONUNO,notif);

 }


});
 }
```

I also libraries . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

there is a ` characheter after notif.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.tree);
remove that charachter and code will run.

Comment: Sorry about the character , it has happened copying the code here .  Before `nm.notify` also this character , but I repeat copying the code has happened here and not the error. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

final NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

```
    //Connect to the button
    Button iconBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_icon);
    //Set the button on click listener
    iconBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent).setTicker("This is a notification marquee")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Message Title")
                    .setContentText("Message Content").build();

            //Show the notification
            nm.notify(1, notification);
        }

    });
```